# PL/SQL : Can we have same name for variable and column

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the tutorial i learned that we cannot have same name of variable and column

[Here is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX_fg0MUDIU&list=PLuCTRl2rPt4aiptyRKJFpHO73sf9gdydy&index=7)

so i tried this

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare 
n1 number;
name varchar(10);
begin
null;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sparsh' || TO_CHAR(45));
select name  into name from Employee;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name);
END;
/
```

Here i have name column in the table and with the same name i declare the variable.

As per the tutorials it should give some error. But it is working fine

Could you please help me in order to clarify.

So can we have variable with same name of column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial is slightly wrong.  It *is* possible to have variables with the same name in SQL and PL/SQL but it is almost certainly a bad idea to do so.

Using variables with the same name will lead to confusing scope issues.  The PL/SQL block will correctly use the PL/SQL `name` for the `INTO` clause, but it would also use it other places you might not expect.  For example, if you tried to use it in the `WHERE` clause the SQL `name` would be used instead.

```
drop table employee;
create table employee(id number, name varchar2(100));
insert into employee values (1, 'Alice');


declare 
    name varchar(10) := 'Bob';
begin
    select name into name from Employee where name = name;
    dbms_output.put_line(name);
END;
/

OUTPUT:
Alice
```

This is the real reason why it's a good practice to name local variables `V_` for "variable", and `P_` for "parameter".  It's not because of some stupid Systems Hungarian notation rules.  (So don't also start naming your variables `_IN_`, `_NUM_`, etc!)  It's because in practice you want to use the same names in PL/SQL and SQL but you don't want to get them confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare 
    name varchar(10) := 'Bob';
begin
    select name into name from Employee where **id= id**;
    dbms_output.put_line(name);
END;
/
```

I am using the same example given by Jon.
See the condition where id = id.
If you use a variable with a name same as of the column name.It would not throw any error but it would certainly astonish you with a huge and unexpectedly large  dataset.
In Conditional predicates column names get prioritized over variable names.
Hence in this case id = id both would be considered as table columns and condition will be evaluated into TRUE for all rows.

There is no such rule while choosing the name of the variables.but it's better to keep the standards.

Answer (score -1):

Should this be something SQL tools like Toad should be picking up on? e.g. if you try to run a query like this it would fail with a message to say something like 'Declared variable name should not be the same as Column name in query'? Or should it be a SQL error thrown? I can't think of any situation where you would want to do this and want the outcome so surely it shouldn't be possible to do it?